# Sharepoint List Not Saving, Giving "Skip To Main Content" Error

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have created a basic list in sharepoint. When I go to create an item in the list, I am able to fill out all of the fields. But when I go to save it, it doesn't submit the form. It gives me the error "Skip to Main Content".

I have several lists where I use the same syntax for the "On New", "On Edit", "OnView", etc. fields in the SharePointIntegration tab of the powerapps form and all of my other lists work fine except for the one which I describe with the error above.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had a Similar situation with my customized form using powerapp.
The issue for me was the read permission I allowed for the users.

I had a custom edit button on the form for editing the form. Users were able to edit the form but unable to Save due to the permission setting.

After realizing it,  I made changes in permission settings by providing edit permission and the issue was solved